# Generate a unique random 4 digit number from another 4 digit number

Tags: algorithms, random

I have a database that has two columns. The first column is an index, the second is the path to a data file. There are two types of data files, X and Y. These data files are then processed and graphs are created from them. So some examples of the rows look like this:

```
ID___| FilePath
0001 | /X/datafile1wfre.dat
0023 | /X/datafile89_jncd.dat
2349 | /Y/datafile983jew_un.dat
3984 | /Y/datafileindj389.dat
```

I am then taking this table, choosing a random row from it, and showing the graph of the data file to the user. After they have spent time looking at the graph, I am then going to ask them, do you think this data file is X or Y?

Let's say someone looks at a graph and this person would like to view that graph at a later point in time. I would then give them an ID of the row. Note: There are ~4000 entries in the table.

Here's the issue, the way to file paths are added to the table, the first half of the table are the paths of X (ID's 0001 - 2000), and the second half of the database are the paths of Y (ID's 2001 - 4000). Someone could easily figure this out and once they see the ID, they would be able to make a prediction of it being X or Y just based on if the ID is above or below 2000.

Here's my goal. I would like to have an algorithm that can take a 4 digit number A and make another (different) 4 digit number B. I want B to be unique to A, no other 4 digit number could make B except A. Here's an example:

```
0239 would create 9834
7783 would create 3892
```

9834 is unique to 0239. No matter what 4 digit number you have, the only way to get 9834 is from 0239. Same with 3892, the only way to get 3892 is from 7783.

This way, I can give the generated 4 digit from the algorithm to the user without having them see the Real ID from the table.

Comment: Could someone help explain how this was unclear? I think I laid out what I'm trying to do clearly but it may need some help, can someone please tell me which part is unclear so I can improve my question?

Comment: Do this once: for each number between 1 and 9999, toss a coin.  Heads, it's X, Tails, it's Y.  Instead of tossing a coin, use a random number generator to deliver numbers between 0 and 1.  If the value is < 0.5, it's X otherwise it's Y.  If you need the number of Xs and Ys to match, you'll need to tweak the output.

Comment: @DanPichelman That might work but I'd like an algorithm that I can use instead of iterating through every number from 0 to 9999

Comment: [Sharing your research helps everyone](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important). Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Comment: Second paragraph is particularly indecipherable.

Comment: @TulainsCórdova I rewrote my question attempting to improve clarity. Does the edit I made accomplish this?

Comment: A hashing algorithm may work here. Ostensibly, the output is not unique, but for a space this small, you can generate all the hashes and deal with collisions as they appear.

Comment: I voted for reopen now that the question is a lot more clear.

Comment: Why don't you just assign each row a guid and present that to the user?

Comment: @EsbenSkovPedersen I'm specifically looking for an algorithm that accomplishes what I want.

Comment: then why don't you simply do sha1, convert to bigint then modulus?

Comment: @EsbenSkovPedersen Wouldn't that produce at some point from 0-9999 a nonunique end result? Have you read my question all the way through? I'm giving an algorithm a unique input, and I want a unique output where the only way to get the same output from the algorithm is from that very same input.

Comment: @TulainsCórdova I've waited some time on the re-open, I know at I site I'm more involved this process usually takes a bit shorter. I think that the question didn't get enough reopen votes, would you recommend posting a meta question about this?

Comment: Tom im just asking because there seems to be many irrelevant details and I want to make sure I understand the question.

Comment: @EsbenSkovPedersen I agree, there are irrelevant details but I wanted to make it as clear as I could and providing those details may have help. I do want to make my question as clear as possible, if you could tell me which parts aren't, I will edit accordingly

Comment: What you are asking is basically a shuffle, correct?

Comment: @EsbenSkovPedersen Yes, that produces **unique outputs**

Comment: You should then remove this part since a shuffle would have to consider the entire table "I would like to have an algorithm that can take a 4 digit number A and make another (different) 4 digit number B"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6389724/php-unique-hashing-function-thats-only-4-digits-doesnt-need-to-be-exact

Comment: From what I understand, what you're looking for is a bijective function that maps 4000 numbers in [4001, 9999] to [1, 4000]. You could shuffle the numbers from 4001 to 9999, take the first 4000 elements and map them to all numbers from 1 to 4000. Or you could try to find a mathematical function that does that, but at that point you may find an answer faster by asking on [math.stackexchange.com](http://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: `That might work but I'd like an algorithm that I can use instead of iterating through every number from 0 to 9999` Is there a specific reason making a list from 0001 to 9999 and shuffling it won't work? Do you have some extremely tight memory or time constraints you've forgotten to mention? (Based on your description of the context, a time constraint small enough to matter seems unlikely.) Are you simply curious if such an algorithm exists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are fundamentally different solutions to this problem as you've presented it.

A truly random mapping from number A (private ID) to number B (public ID) can be created if you have an independent source of random.  Every time you create another row and are assigned number A read from random and create number B.  To ensure B is unique you will have to search all existing B's before assigning it.  This would be the hardest for anyone to reverse engineer.  It's basicly what cryptography calls a one time pad.  It's also increasingly prohibitive as you get closer and closer to fully populating the space you've allowed.  You eventually get to where there is only 1 number left to assign as a B. You have to wait to find it randomly and you have to search to prove uniqueness on every attempt.

A fixed transformation of number A into B by a function.  This avoids becoming prohibitive even when fully populating the space.  It also risks the user guessing the algorithm.  This can be mitigated if instead of simply using a hash to do this, you encrypt the number A.  There are encryption algorithms that produce the same size crypto text as plain text and take a cryptovariable (key).   Done this way it wouldn't matter if they guessed how you created B so long as the cryptovariable (key) was still a secret.  You would want to use a [format preserving encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Format-preserving_encryption).  This gives you the ability to predict A from a B but if you index B on the database this shouldn't be needed.

If you feel that is overkill you could look into a shuffle that simply obfuscates A.  This risks them guessing the shuffle unless it also uses a crypto variable.

It's also worth considering if A is even still needed.  If the only thing A provides is a unique identifier then there is no point in being able to convert back to A and no reason to store A in the database when B is all that is needed.  This means all you have to do is uniquely [randomize the auto increment ID](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/72212/randomizing-the-auto-increment-in-mysql) because this will give you B to start with.  Some DB's already provide this. This way you have unique id's that don't predict x or y and avoid an unneeded level of indirection.

Answer (score 1):

**Considering that:**

- The number of IDs is finite and small (roughly 2k rows in one table and 2k in the other table)
- The "generated alias ID" must be composed of 4 numbers, meaning the number of collisiones will be too high if you try any hash function.

**Then I recommend:**

- You preload the alias ID in another column of the same table, so you don't have to calculate it in real time.

**I created this solution using bash** to create the pairs, maybe you can replicate in another language:

1. I created a file containing strings from 0000 to 4000

   `$ seq -f "%04g" 0 4000 > /tmp/data.txt`
2. I created a second file with strings 0000 to 9999 (this will be the fake IDs)

   `$ seq -f "%04g" 0 9999 > /tmp/data2.txt`
3. I scrambled the second file:

   `$ sort -U /tmp/data2.txt > /tmp/data3.txt`
4. I truncated the resulting file to exactly the first 4001 rows

   `$ head -n 4001 > /tmp/data4.txt`
5. Then I paired all original IDs with their alias IDs

   `$ paste data.txt data4.txt > data5.txt`

After that you have a file (data5.txt) that you can use to populate both your tables with the sequential ID and it's random 4 number ID.

```
0000    3675
0001    2464
0002    1808
0003    9569
0004    3309
...
3996    9843
3997    7497
3998    7892
3999    3062
4000    5687
```

---